# Adobe ADT ANT Build - Unable to use [Embed] Tags

Tags: actionscript-3, ant, air, adobe, adt

I'm attempting to use ANT to compile and package up an iOS IPA file using the Adobe SDK tools. I need to use ANT, because the build requires a tonne of RAM, and Flash Builder gets Java heap space issues when I compile (even though I've increased the max ram in the ini file).

This is what the core of my ANT build looks like:

```
    <!-- Build the SWF and save it in the publish directory --> 
<target name="3. Compile SWF" depends="2. Build New Directories"> 
    <mxmlc 
        file="${MAIN_CLASS}" 
        output="${OUTPUT_SWF}" 
        debug="${DEBUG_FLAG}" 
        failonerror="true">         
        <load-config filename="${MOBI_CONFIG_FILE}"/>
        <define name="MOBI_PROJECT::IS_iOS_BUILD" value="${IS_iOS_BUILD}" />
        <define name="MOBI_PROJECT::DEBUG" value="${DEBUG_FLAG}" />
        <source-path path-element="${MOBI_DIR}/src"/>

        <library-path file="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks/locale/en_US" append="true"/>
        <library-path dir="${MOBI_LIB_RELEASE_DIR}" includes="*.swc" append="true"/>

        <compiler.library-path dir="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks" append="true">
            <include name="libs/*" />
        </compiler.library-path>

        <compiler.external-library-path dir="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks/libs/air">
            <include name="**/*.swc" />
        </compiler.external-library-path>
        <compiler.external-library-path dir="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks/libs">
            <include name="**/*.swc" />
        </compiler.external-library-path>           
        <compiler.external-library-path dir="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks/libs/mx">
            <include name="**/*.swc" />
        </compiler.external-library-path>
    </mxmlc>
</target>

<!-- Package the application to an ipa file & save it in the publish directory --> 
<target name="4. Package Application" depends="3. Compile SWF"> 
    <java jar="${ADT}" fork="true" failonerror="true"> 
        <arg value="-package"/>
        <arg value="-target"/>
        <arg value="ipa-test"/>

        <arg value="-provisioning-profile"/>
        <arg value="${iOS_PROVISIONING}"/>

        <arg value="-storetype"/>
        <arg value="pkcs12"/>

        <arg value="-keystore"/>
        <arg value="${iOS_KEYSTORE}"/>

        <arg value="-storepass"/>
        <arg value="${iOS_PASS}"/>

        <arg value="${IPA_FILE}"/>
        <arg value="${APP_DESCRIPTOR}"/>
        <arg value="${OUTPUT_SWF}"/>
    </java> 
</target>
```

I'm using Flex 4.6 SDK with Air 3.4 beta SDK and using airmobile-config.xml from the SDK as my config file.

But when I run this I get the following error:

```
4. Package Application:
 [java] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unable to find named traits: mx.core::SoundAsset
 [java]     at adobe.abc.Domain.resolveTypeName(Domain.java:232)
 [java]     at adobe.abc.Domain.resolveTypeName(Domain.java:149)
 [java]     at adobe.abc.GlobalOptimizer$InputAbc.resolveTypeName(GlobalOptimizer.java:272)
 [java]     at adobe.abc.GlobalOptimizer$InputAbc.readInstance(GlobalOptimizer.java:1000)
 [java]     at adobe.abc.GlobalOptimizer$InputAbc.readAbc(GlobalOptimizer.java:390)
 [java]     at adobe.abc.GlobalOptimizer$InputAbc.readAbc(GlobalOptimizer.java:278)
 [java]     at adobe.abc.LLVMEmitter.generateBitcode(LLVMEmitter.java:320)
 [java]     at com.adobe.air.ipa.AOTCompiler.convertAbcToLlvmBitcodeImpl(AOTCompiler.java:516)
 [java]     at com.adobe.air.ipa.BitcodeGenerator.main(BitcodeGenerator.java:80)
 [java] Compilation failed while executing : ADT
```

If I remove all my [Embed] tags of audio, then the error is still there, but it complains about 'mx.core::ByteArrayAsset'. If I remove every single [Embed] tag in the project, then it compiles ok.

I've tried to force the SoundAsset class to be embedded by putting this line in my code:

```
import mx.core.SoundAsset;
...
new SoundAsset();
```

I've even gone into the Flex SDK and copied out the SoundAsset and ByteArrayAsset classes and put them in my project, but none of these things help.

Can anyone please tell me how to compile an IPA file via ANT while still keeping my [Embed] tags?

Comment: try to manually add core.swc file from FLEX_SDK/frameworks/libs directory

Comment: I just tried the following, as suggested, but still get the same error.
<compiler.library-path dir="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks/libs/mx" append="true">
 <include name="mx.swc"/>
</compiler.library-path>
<compiler.library-path dir="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks/libs" append="true">
 <include name="core.swc"/>
</compiler.library-path>

Comment: Ok, so I've figured out it's the [Embed] tags that are causing the build to fail, but I really need those tags, so I need to find a work around.

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed the problem!

I *think* the problem was in the way I was linking to the libraries. I ended up deleting all my hand made ANT settings and instead exporting the settings from my Flash Builder project, and just using those.

Full details in this article here, it saved my life:
http://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/multi/compilation-results-flex-builder-flex.html